# Specify a model with crossed and nested factors in sas proc mixed

Tags: sas, anova, mixed-models

### Brief question

How do I write the `model` statement in `proc mixed` to study the interaction between a factor with a second factor nested within a third factor?

- So `factor_1` is independent from the others (like year is independent from location)
- but `factor_2` is a subdivision of `factor_3` (like province is a subdivision of state).

I would expect it to be `model factor_1 * factor_2(factor_3);` but that does not work.

### The real problem and context

I am trying to model [this Crossed - Nested Design example](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat502/lesson/4/4.3) from an Analysis of Variance and Design of Experiments course of Eberly College of Science using the techniques from [this Nested Treatment Design example](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat502/lesson/4/4.2) and the instructions given in [this video](https://youtu.be/yzPkljI4HFs?t=657).

#### Loading my data with

```
data PRODUCTION;
    infile datalines dsd dlm='09'x;
    array _M {6} _temporary_ (1 1 2 2 3 3);
    array _C {6} _temporary_ (1 2 1 2 1 2);
    array _O {6} _M1_C1 _M1_C2 _M2_C1 _M2_C2 _M3_C1 _M3_C2;
    input Power _M1_C1 _M1_C2 _M2_C1 _M2_C2 _M3_C1 _M3_C2;
    do _i = 1 to 6;
        Machine = _M(_i);
        Config  = _C(_i);
        Out_put = _O(_i);
        output;
    end;
    drop _:;
    datalines;
1   10.2    4.2 12.0    4.1 13.1    4.1
1   13.1    5.2 13.5    6.1 12.9    6.1
2   16.2    8.0 12.6    4.0 12.9    2.2
2   16.9    9.1 14.6    6.1 13.7    3.8
3   13.8    2.5 12.9    3.7 11.8    2.7
3   14.9    4.4 15.0    5.0 13.5    4.1
;run;
```

#### running this analysis

```
proc mixed data=PRODUCTION 
    method=type3 
    plots=all;

    class Machine Config Power;
    model Out_put = 
            Machine 
            Config(Machine) 
            Power
            Machine*Power 
            Config(Machine)*Power;
    store PRODUCTION;
run;
proc plm restore=PRODUCTION;
    lsmeans Machine Config(Machine) Power
        Power*Machine Power*Config(Machine)
        / adjust=tukey plot=meanplot cl lines;
    ods exclude diffplot;
run;
```

#### I get this in the log

```
54          model Out_put =
55                  Machine
56                  Config(Machine)
2                                                          The SAS System                              08:31 Sunday, January 3, 2021

57                  Power
58                  Machine*Power
59                  Config(Machine)*Power;
                             _
                             22
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a name.  
60          store PRODUCTION;
ERROR: Variable NAME not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribute law wise

```
        Config(Machine)*Power
```

might be one of these (*of which `model` statement does accept*)

```
        Config(Machine*Power)
        Power*Config(Machine)
```

The `MODEL` statement parses complex effects specifications according to algebraic expansion.

The SAS/STAT User's Guide section ["Specification of Effects"](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect028.htm) bullet point for nested effects is

> - Nested effects are specified by following a main effect or crossed effect with a classification variable or list of classification variables enclosed in parentheses. **The main effect or crossed effect is nested within the effects listed in parentheses**: `B(A) C(B*A) D*E(C*B*A)`. In this example, **`B(A)`** is read "B nested within A."
>   ***NOTE: My bold. For me, things inside () are often concepted as the nested thing (deeper tier) within a hierarchy. So I might struggle here a little if I indeed need to mentally crossover concepts.***

The SAS/STAT User's Guide section ["Parameterization of PROC GLM Models"](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect030.htm) states

> The GLM procedure constructs a linear model according to the specifications in the MODEL statement. Each effect generates one or more columns in a design matrix . This section shows precisely how  is built.

and discusses the process and design matrix created.

Comment: Thanks:it works. If you add a decent explanation why, you get an extra 10 rep.